# not able to login to myadminphp.Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

mysqli_real_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

I have no idea how to solve this error. i am using google sql cloud, where can i change the utf8 settings in gcloud
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

Comment: What version of MySQL server?  What version of client?

Comment: I am using MySQL 8.0, client version i am not aware. can you tell how to check

Comment: Is there client mysqladmin?  Or something else?

Comment: You've tagged 'phpmyadmin' — is this really when trying to log in with phpMyAdmin? If so, which phpMyAdmin version are you using and do you get the error message before any login dialog or after entering your credentials? Which PHP versions are you using?

Comment: yes i get error when i enter credentials. i have install phpMyAdmin using gcloud . it is the latest version

Comment: @RickJames i use link creeated by gcloud to use phpMyAdmin

Comment: it is 4.9.5 version

Comment: Is there a reason you're still using the quite outdated 4.9.5 version instead of the newer 5.2.1 ? I'd try upgrading your phpMyAdmin and seeing if the problem still occurs. Note that version 5 has more modern requirements than version 4, so your PHP can't be ancient, for instance.